# Prove that $R = \Bbb C \left [X,Y,Z \right ]/ \left \langle 2X^2Y - 3XY^3 + Z \right \rangle$ is a unique factorization domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R = \Bbb C \left [X,Y,Z \right ]/ \left \langle 2X^2Y - 3XY^3 + Z \right \rangle.$ Show that $R$ is a unique factorization domain.

How do I show that? Can anybody please help me proving that?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** $:$ Let $S = \Bbb C \left [X,Y \right ].$ Then $\alpha : = 2X^2Y - 3XY^3 \in S.$Therefore $$R = S \left [Z \right ] / \left \langle Z  + \alpha \right \rangle \cong S$$ since $\alpha \in S.$ Hence $R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C \left [X,Y \right ]$ as rings and since $\Bbb C \left [X,Y \right ]$ is a unique factorization domain (by Gauss's theorem) it follows that $R$ is also a unique factorization domain, as required.

Can anybody please check my reasoning above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I say that $$\Bbb C \left [X,Y,Z \right ]/ \left \langle 2X^2Y - 3XY^3 + Z \right \rangle \cong \Bbb C\left [X,Y,3X Y^3 - 2 X^2 Y\right ] = \Bbb C \left [X,Y \right ]$$ as rings?

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Crostul for your verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is entirely correct.

Comment: Thanks @Servaes for your verification.